# get page number in Openerp RML report

Tags: report, odoo

I want to ask about openerp 6.1 report rml

I want to check if number of pages in my report If I have more than one page I have to print "There is another Data in the next page" also If I am in the second page to print "there is another data in the previous page" and so in till the last page

is there is a way to check it in report something like that

```
 [["" if pagenumber()>1 else "second page paragraph" ]] 
 [["" if pagenumber()==pagecount else "last page" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<pageNumber/>` tag in rml file e.g.

```
<pageGraphics>
    <drawCentredString x="10.5cm" y="0.8cm">Page: <pageNumber/>
    </drawCentredString>
</pageGraphics>
```

for reference go to `settings > company > header/footer` tab. in this you will get the reference for page number.

Comment: thanks Atul for your answer but If I need to check if I am in the first page to print something and in last page to print another things in the middle pages to print other things what I have to do